# Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{\sin z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Question is a fully solved exercise in Gamelin's complex analysis.

> Exercise : Consider the Laurent series expansion for $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ that converges on the circle $\{|z|=4\}$. Find the coefficients $a_0,a_{-1},a_{-2},a_{-3}$. Determine the largest open set on which the series converges.

Solution :  The only zeros of $\sin z$ are at the integral multiples of $\pi$. These are then the only singularities of $\frac{1}{\sin z}$, and they are all simple poles. **The largest open annular set containing the cirlce and to which $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ extends analytically is then the annulus $\{\pi <|z|<2\pi\}$. The annulus is then the largest open set on which the Laurent series converges.**

We have expansions
 $$\sin z =z-\cdots \rm{near~~}z=0$$ 
 $$\sin z =-(z-\pi)-\cdots \rm{near~~}z=\pi$$ 
 $$\sin z =-(z+\pi)-\cdots \rm{near~~}z=-\pi$$

Just by considering inverses, long divisions, we see that

$$\frac{1}{\sin z} =\frac{1}{z}+\rm{analytic}$$ 
 $$\frac{1}{\sin z}=-\frac{1}{z-\pi}+\rm{analytic}$$ 
 $$\frac{1}{\sin z} =-\frac{1}{z+\pi}+\rm{analytic}$$

We conclude that if $$f_1(z)=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z-\pi}-\frac{1}{z+\pi}$$ then **$f_0(z)=1/\sin z-f_1(z)$ is analytic for $|z|>2\pi$.** Thus, $$\frac{1}{\sin z}=f_0(z)+f_1(z)$$ is the Laurent decomposition of $1/\sin z$.

I do not understand what ever is written in bold. I see that $f(z)$ is analytic for $|z|>\pi$.. could not figure out why $f_0(z)$ is analytic for $|z|<2\pi$..

We have $$f_3(z)=\frac{3}{\sin z}-f_1(z)=\left(\frac{1}{\sin z}-\frac{1}{z}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{\sin z}-\frac{1}{z-pi}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{\sin z}-\frac{1}{z+\pi}\right)$$

Each function in the brackets is analytic at $0,\pi,-\pi$ respectively.  does it imply sum is analytic?? That too in $|z|<2\pi$$??

$f_1(z)$ is just same as $f_3(z)$ except a constant.. so, if $f_3(z)$ is analytic then so would be $f_1(z)$..

Help me to fill the gaps..

Comment: $\sin z$ is entire, and its zeros are at $k \pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, all or order one, and $\sin'(k \pi) = (-1)^k$,  hence the singularities of $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$ all are poles of order one at $k \pi$ with residue $(-1)^k$ i.e. $\frac{1}{\sin(z)} - \sum_{ k = - \lfloor R/\pi \rfloor}^{\lfloor R/\pi \rfloor} \frac{(-1)^k}{z - k \pi}$ is analytic on $|z| \le R$. can you finish ?

Comment: @user1952009 : Thanks for your interest... I can not use residue now.. residue comes much after this

Comment: that the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=a$ a pole of order $1$ is $Res(f(z),z=a) = C$ simply means that $f(z) \sim \frac{C}{z-a}$ in the neighborhood of $z=a$, and by the definition of a pole of order $1$ : $(z-a)  f(z)$ is analytic in the neighborhood of $z=a$, hence $f(z) -  \frac{C}{z-a}$ is analytic in the neighborhood of $z=a$...

Comment: I know what is a residue but i think i should not use that information @user1952009